# using a select query to create a record in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Probably a really easy question but I created a record that has 3 columns.  The third column I am going to assign a value later.  The query selects 2 columns for the record.  What am I missing?  The error that is thrown is that there are "too many values" in my select statment.

```
create or replace Procedure Pledges3 
(IDdonor In Int, flag Out Varchar)
as 
type allPledges is record(iddonor dd_pledge.iddonor%type, idstatus dd_status.idstatus%type, flag Varchar(25));
allPledges2 allpledges;
Begin
Select dd_pledge.iddonor, dd_status.idstatus 
  into allpledges2 
    from dd_donor
      join dd_pledge on dd_donor.iddonor=dd_pledge.iddonor
        join dd_status on dd_pledge.idstatus=dd_status.idstatus
          where dd_pledge.IDdonor=305;
    if allpledges2.idstatus = '10' THEN 
     Flag := 'True';
      elsif allpledges2.idstatus= '20' THEN 
        Flag := 'False';
    End if;
    dbms_output.put_line(flag);
End;
```

Comment: You can just select null as the third column, and reassign it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code, corrected:

```
create or replace Procedure Pledges3 
(IDdonor In Int, flag Out Varchar)
as 
type allPledges is record(iddonor dd_pledge.iddonor%type, idstatus dd_status.idstatus%type, flag Varchar(25));
allPledges2 allpledges;
Begin
Select dd_pledge.iddonor, dd_status.idstatus, null 
  into allpledges2 
    from dd_donor
      join dd_pledge on dd_donor.iddonor=dd_pledge.iddonor
        join dd_status on dd_pledge.idstatus=dd_status.idstatus
          where dd_pledge.IDdonor=305;
    if allpledges2.idstatus = '10' THEN 
     allPledges2.Flag := 'True';
      elsif allpledges2.idstatus= '20' THEN 
        allPledges2.Flag := 'False';
    End if;
    dbms_output.put_line(allPledges2.flag);
End;
```

Comment: So the code compiles with no errors but I do not get the put line message for the variable flag.  Is there any reason that this is happening?

Comment: Execute set serveroutput on; command before executing this procedure...then will show...

Comment: Well I add the set serveroutput on; before my create procedure statement and I get the error message "missing or invalid option" and the message points to this line of code.  I then call the procedure from new procedure and put set severoutput on; before the new procedure and take that statement out of the calling procedure and I still receive the same error message.

Comment: where are you executing ur statement in sqlplus on in sql developer ? if sqlplus then just run first serveroutput then execute procedure if developer then run as script...

Comment: in sqldeveloper.  So all I need to do is run the set serveroutput on statement once at that turns it on for the whole session?

Comment: right... or run both same time as script... first serveroutput command then execute ur procedure... the serveroutput output will at the time of procedure execution not at the time of creation..